# fix timing for dropped frame using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have downloaded a streaming video that has dropped some frames. In VLC player playing these parts causes freezing. How do I remove these skipped timestamp from the video and reencode using ffmpeg?

Comment: Any audio in them?

Comment: @Mulvya Yes it has audio.